# Tabcontrol having listview as elements

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tabcontrol

I got tabcontrol made in xaml code. It's items are listviews made in xaml code as DataTemplate. When i change Tabcontrol's tab selection on my listview disapears. It was set when creating it.

```
<TabControl Name="TheTab" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0,10,0,0" Style="{StaticResource startTabStyle}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListTabName}" 
                       SelectionChanged="TheTab_SelectionChanged"
                        SelectedIndex="0"

                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListView Name="Lista" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" />
                        </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

That it is mine tabcontrol with listview.

Comment: Please provide us with some code! Impossible to help you otherwise..

Comment: Edited, adding some code. When i change tab, none of listview items is selected as it is at beggining.